# Show $(\lambda I-A)^{-1}$ is unbounded iff $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $A$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Assume $A$ is non-singular linear operator $(\lambda I-A)^{-1}$ is an unbounded linear operator iff $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $A$. Any reference for this proof is welcome.

Attempt: The $(<=)$ direction is true since $\lambda$ is eigenvalue iff $(\lambda I-A)$ is singular. Then for some $v_n\to v_*$ where $v_*$ is a corresponding eigenvector, $(\lambda I-A)v_n =\epsilon_n \to 0$. Then we can find $|(\lambda I-A)^{-1}(\epsilon_n/|\epsilon_n|)|=|v_n|/|\epsilon_n|\to |v_*|/|\epsilon_n|\to \infty$.

(=>) if $\lambda$ is not eigenvalue, then $(\lambda I-A)^{-1}$ exists for any vector and thus bounded because $|Au|$ is bounded for $u$ on a unit ball by extreme value theorem.

This "proof" is just my intuition and I have no formal education in functional analysis, especially when $A$ is not finite.

Comment: You mean, when $A$ is not defined on a finite-dimensional space?

Comment: @Math1000 Yes. That is, $A$ is not a matrix of finite size.

Comment: An eigenvalue is a complex number $\lambda$ so that $A-\lambda I$ is not injective, and so the inverse you're talking about is not even defined.

Comment: Indeed, as @qbert pointed out, this question is ill-posed.

Comment: @qbert it is not defined on eigenvectors. But the point is that it is unbounded on domain that it is indeed defined.

Comment: @qbert it's like prove $1/x$ is unbounded.

Comment: @DanielLi huh? Are you trying to define the operator on some sort of complement (which you need to be careful about defining, in fact you should say what you mean to start with). Also, the extreme value theorem does not hold in infinite dimensions because the unit ball is not compact.

Comment: @qbert Ok I'm not an expert on this but here is the article I'm reading:

Comment: @qbert "Let $\lambda_*$ be the sup of all \lambda such that $\lambda I-P$ is unbounded linear operator". I think the author is referring to all eigenvalues but not sure. That's why I asked.